# Disable editing a form method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, paypal

I am having a problem, people is able to change this while connection to the paypal and they are able to change the ammount of how much they are able to buy for the set they are buying.Could i disable editing this or how could i do to prevent people for editing this?.

```
<form method="post" name="paypal_form" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
    <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">


    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">


    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="fliphotell@hotmail.com">


    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://fliphotel.org">


    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="Flowy">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://fliphotel.org">


    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://fliphotel.org/pp/paypal.php?action=ipn">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="2">


    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Flip Diamonds">


    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="7">
    <center><br><br>If you are not automatically redirected to paypal within 5 seconds...<br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Click Here"></center>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can disable inputs by using the disabled attribute.  Perhaps you can wait until the connection is finished before removing the disabled attribute.

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
 First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
 Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" disabled><br>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: $p->add_field('amount', $cost); how could i add disabled on this one?

Comment: You have to be way more descriptive if you really want a helpful answer.  I assume that is PHP which will eventually render HTML.  If so you can either modify the add_field method to take a disabled argument or a hacky way is to target the form via javascript and disable the inputs.  Either way it looks like you are pretty far off.